# UICollectionView is not allowing full scroll --- last few rows are cut off

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that holds a bunch of a photos.

However, if I scroll to the bottom the scrollview does not let me scroll to the bottom of the last few rows (it snaps back). I have tried override the collectionView.contentSize and just adding 1000 to the height but it doesn't fix the problem.

collectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(collectionView.contentSize.width, collectionView.contentSize.height + 1000)

Here is a video of the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fH57_pL0OjQ&list=UUIctdpq1Pzujc0u0ixMSeVw

Here is my code to create cells:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
        {
            var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("selectPhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as B_SelectPhotoControllerViewCell
            let reuseCount = ++cell.reuseCount
            let asset = currentAssetAtIndex(indexPath.item)
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize:_cellSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil)//the target size here can be set to CGZero for a super blurry preview
            {
                result, info in
                if reuseCount == cell.reuseCount
                {
                    cell.imageView.image = result
                    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self._cellSize.width,self._cellSize.height)
                }
            }
            return cell
        }


private func currentAssetAtIndex(index:NSInteger)->PHAsset
    {
        if let fetchResult = _assetsFetchResults
        {
            return fetchResult[index] as PHAsset
        }else
        {
            return _selectedAssets[index]
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

Because I am adding this as a child view controller, there seems to be some problems with the offsetting of the scrollview. I haven't fixed it yet but when open this view without adding it as a child view to another view controller, the scrollview is the correct size

Comment: Try turning off adjustScrollViewInsets (see example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/j1ez5.png)

Comment: I have that toggled off but the problem persists :(

Comment: How'd you make your collection view? Storyboard? Do you have appropriate constraints?

Comment: It is in the storyboard, and I have the bounds of each edge set to 0 relative to the parent

Comment: I do suspect something is up here though!

Comment: Ok this seems to be the root of the problem: because this is a child view controller, its view is getting set to the wrong height

Comment: Try reducing the height of UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was adding this as a child view controller.

As a result, after doing some animations, the UICollectionView bounds were sizing to the view it was attached to. As a result its height was wrong and hence why it was getting cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question from a quick Google and felt I could add something useful.

I am running a segmentedControl with a UIView that changes to different UICollectionViews on the segment change and I couldn't get the collectionView to scroll fully down.

This may not be the solution for all, but I found that if I went to the XIB I was loading in the view and set size to freeform and decrease it by the size of a cell I had removed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

suspect your CollectionView's bottomAchor was not set correctly to the parent uiview's safeAreaLayoutGuide bottomAnchor